# Firefox Error "We’re having trouble finding that site" on random pages

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, firefox

In recent weeks while surfing internet I receive instant error: **We’re having trouble finding that site** on random pages and after refreshing page it loads normally. I reinstalled Network adapter also used some `netsh` commands (`netsh winsock reset`) but no luck.

I use Firefox ver 66 but also tested on Edge browser and same result happens. (Edge error: **can’t reach this page**) .

I don't have this problem on WiFi so i don't think its on ISP side or base connection.

Answer (score 1):

The very first 'zero-effort' test on any consumer networking issue is to power-cycle all network-capable hardware in the building.
Don't hibernate or sleep, fully power down.

Switch off everything - computers, TVs & 'smart' boxes, all wifi, all ethernet hubs/switches & the router/modem itself.

Wait at least 2 minutes, **don't rush**; then power all back on from the 'outside world' inwards, modem/router first, computers last, leaving at least one minute between each. You want each device to be fully booted & ready before powering up the next in line.
Test again.

It sounds like a DNS issue, so this will wipe a whole slew of potentially stale data from your devices.

Comment: We don't have hubs , but one TV and some Phones on the WiFi network. although we had some power outages in last days, so "Everything off" mode happens, but not exactly the way you said, and I'll try that.